# C program not printing

Tags: c, function

I have written the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void inttobusn(int val, int n, char* bus)
{
    int i;
    unsigned int digit;

    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
            digit = pow(2, (n-1-i));
            if (digit <= val) {
                    val -= digit;
                    bus[i] = '1';
                    //printf("hello %c",bus[i]);
            } else {
                    bus[i] = '0';
            }       
     }
} 
main(){
  char* bus;
  inttobusn(37,8,bus);
  int i=0;
  //printf("%s",bus);
  for(i=0;i<12;i++){
      printf("%c",bus[i]);
  }
}
```

But on running it doesn't print the elements of the array `bus`. It doesn't print anything. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Please could someone point out?

Comment: Format your code better - that will be a good start to finding bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is buggy! you don't allocate memory for the `bus[]` array, and are trying to access values at garbage location as e.g `bus[i] = 0;` -- Undefined Behavior in `C` standard, Undefined means you can't predict how your code will behave at runtime.

This code compiled because syntax-wise the code is correct but at runtime the OS will detect illegal memory access and can terminate your code. (interesting to note: as OS detects memory right violation by a process -- An invalid access to valid memory gives: SIGSEGV And access to an invalid address gives: SIGBUS). In the worst case your program may seem execute without any failure, producing garbage results.

To simply correct it define `bus` array as `char bus[N];` else allocated memory dynamically using [void* malloc (size_t size);](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Additionally, suggestion to your from @Lochemage and @Ran Eldan:

You need to declare bus with a specific size, like `char bus[12]`. It has to be at least large enough to fit `12` chars because your for loop at the end is iterating through that many (and you can check your code working with this suggestion @[codepade](http://codepad.org/b1RZvhwa)).

Also there is no return type to `main()` in your code, its should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: Yeah, you need to declare bus with a specific size, like char bus[12].  It has to be at least large enough to fit 12 chars because your for loop at the end is iterating through that many.

Comment: Also there is no return type to main, and the call for pow is ambiguous, need to add casting to double i.e. `(double)2`.

Comment: `int main()` is not valid either. It should be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. (Or "some other implementation-defined manner". Does _your_ implementation document any other acceptable form for `main()`?)

Comment: @ElchononEdelson yes but here *not valid* is bit wrong na, good are `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv, char* env[])`

Comment: It may be that `int main(int argc, char **argv, char* env[])` is valid (as I said, does _your_ implementation define that?), but anything other than `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` only valid if the implementation explicitly documents it as such. (And no, POSIX does not require `int main(int argc, char **argv, char* env[])` to be a valid alternative.)

Comment: My point primarily is that if you're correcting someone's misuse of `main()`, the correction should be correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory allocated to `bus` so this is an **undefined behavior**. Either write

```
char bus[some sufficient size];
```

or use `malloc`, `realloc` to reserve memory.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize you bus variable.

```
char* bus = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Take it easy, bro. We all know how to replace `new` with `malloc`. Chillax.

Comment: Yes! I wrote that too fast :P I changed it.